# Player movement touch input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unityscript

I am working on a 2D game and now I'm at the end of it! (happiness). But I can not make it move in android. What is wrong in the code below?

When I run the application in UNITY console does not accuse any errors.

```
  using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Bee : MonoBehaviour {

        public float velocity;

        public Transform bee;
        private Animator animator;

        public bool isGrounded = true;
        public float force;

        public float jumpTime = 0.4f;
        public float jumpDelay = 0.4f;
        public bool jumped = false;
        public Transform ground;

        private Gerenciador gerenciador;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {
            gerenciador = FindObjectOfType (typeof(Gerenciador)) as Gerenciador;
            animator = bee.GetComponent<Animator> ();
            gerenciador.StartGame ();

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update ()
        {

            Move();

        }



        void Move()
        {

            isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast (bee.transform.position, ground.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Floor"));

            foreach (UnityEngine.Touch touch in Input.touches) {

                if (this.GetComponent<GUITexture> ().HitTest (touch.position)) {

                    if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended) {

                        if (this.name == "Right") {

                            animator.SetBool ("Run", true);
                            bee.transform.Translate (Vector2.right * velocity* Time.deltaTime);
                            bee.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 0);
                        }

                        if (this.name == "Left") {

                            animator.SetBool ("Run", true);
                            bee.transform.Translate (Vector2.right * velocity* Time.deltaTime);
                            bee.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 180);
                        }

                        if (this.name == "Up" && isGrounded && !jumped) {

                            animator.SetTrigger ("JumpB");
                            bee.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (transform.up * force);
                            jumpTime = jumpDelay;
                            jumped = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                        animator.SetBool ("Run", false);


                    }
                }
            }


            if (jumpTime >= 0f) {
                jumpTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if (jumpTime <= 0 && isGrounded && jumped) {

                animator.SetTrigger ("groundB");
                jumped = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to debug your code using Unity Remote you can find it on Google Play. This app allows you to debug touches in Unity Editor.

Comment: Just a minor thing, if you ever think of porting this to PC, locking your movement to your frame rate is a bad idea!

Comment: @Draken if for android =]

Comment: Read here for more information on why it's generally a bad idea:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/when-should-i-use-a-fixed-or-variable-time-step

You always need to be able to guarantee a constant frame rate at the moment, and that isn't always possible

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code keeps calling the movement part and it messes up the code because you don't check if it is the start of the `touchPhase`.

So when the user touches the button, the `Move` method is called for each frame and because `touchPhase` hasn't ended (player is still touching), it passes this line `if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended)`.

That means that this part is getting called for all the frames while player is still touching the `GUItexture` and I think that you should just do the movement if the `touchPhase` has begun:

```
if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
    if (this.name == "Right") {
        animator.SetBool ("Run", true);
        bee.transform.Translate (Vector2.right * velocity* Time.deltaTime);
        bee.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 0);
    }
    if (this.name == "Left") {
        animator.SetBool ("Run", true);
        bee.transform.Translate (Vector2.right * velocity* Time.deltaTime);
        bee.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 180);
    }
    if (this.name == "Up" && isGrounded && !jumped) {
        animator.SetTrigger ("JumpB");
        bee.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (transform.up * force);
        jumpTime = jumpDelay;
        jumped = true;
    }
}
```